# How can I check whether the phone has GPS device or not?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to find piece of code which can tell me whether the android phone has GPS device or not? Most of the samples I am getting in search results are telling whether GPS is enabled or not. What I am interested in is whether Android phone has Physical GPS device or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public boolean hasGPSDevice(Context context)
    {
    final LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if ( mgr == null ) return false;
    final List<String> providers = mgr.getAllProviders();
    if ( providers == null ) return false;
    return providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
```

Comment: + 1 Your answer makes sense. But in the emulator even if I do `GPS Support = No` this code returns true. Any ideas? May be this will work well on a phone without GPS it will return false but not sure...

Answer (score 21):

Starting with API level 8 (Froyo), you can use the following code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
boolean hasGPS = packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
```

Comment: Tested on Kindle Fire (without GPS) and it works like a charm.

Comment: Less process time than LocationManager#getAllProviders()