# Google Play - Your device isn't compatible with this version

Tags: android, gps, google-play, installation

I'm not getting Google Play - Your device isn't compatible with this version for only one device - zen ultratab a700 3g (**This device does not have gps**) . All other devices are able to download the app(**devices with gps**).

**Permissions I use in Android Manifest**

```
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />    

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

I Added  `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />` but still getting same error on the said device (without gps).

But if i run the  project on the tablet or install using signed apk directly then the app installs but gives error on installing on google play

I referred to following links:

[Google Play - Your device isn't compatible with this version - ASUS Transformer TF101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047486/google-play-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-asus-transformer)

["your device isn't compatible with this version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670002/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version)

[Play store reports "Your device isn't compatible with this version" but it installs via adb just fine on Nexus7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484209/play-store-reports-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-but-it-insta)

Comment: having you difine any camera related future ??

Comment: check it and let me know for that

Comment: the app uses camera intent which works fine also

Comment: ohk let me check for that

Comment: having you find solution for that

Comment: Did not find any solution ! added 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />   also additionally but still same error

Comment: still which type of error?

Comment: same error device not compatible

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are still using some of the permissions:

android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" && android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

You should have a fall back in your code to check if a device can handle GPS.

If it can't then it should do something else but at least run on the device.

[How can I check whether the phone has GPS device or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664355/how-can-i-check-whether-the-phone-has-gps-device-or-not)

Comment: Google play is not letting the app installed, writing code to check gps will run only when the app is installed  !!